Serverless v4 - exit status 1
On MacOS, I updated from Node.js version 16 to Node.js version 20.15.
I installed serverless v4. When I check the version or run "serverless update," it always returns "exit status 1."
I'm not sure what to do next as this message doesn't seem to mean anything.


Check Node.js Installation
node -v

Reinstall Serverless
npm uninstall -g serverless

npm install -g serverless@4

Clear npm Cache
npm cache clean --force

Check Dependencies
Check Environment Variables
Update npm
npm install -g npm@latest


It worked. Thanks!
I still don't know what went wrong, but at least now it's working properly.
